# Can xmgrace produce 1D plots?

Tags: xmgrace

[image]Is it possible to get in xmgrace a 1D plot, i.e., a line with an arrow in front of it, subdivided in labeled subregions by means of vertical bars?
Thank you for your attention!

Comment: It is certainly possible. Could you post a picture (even a sketch) or what you want to achieve so that it will be easier to draft an answer?

Comment: Is it possible to get a structure like the one above with names on top of each region of the 1D line and an adjusted range on the axis? Thanks for any possible hint!

Answer (score 0):

As I said in a comment, it is certainly possible, although not exactly comfortable.

- Open `xmgrace`, go to `Plot` -> `Graph appearance...`, select the `Frame` tab and set the line style to `None`.
- Go to `Plot` -> `Axis properties...`:

  - select the `X` axis and tick `Zero axis`. Untick `Display tick labels` and `Display tick marks` if you want to get rid of those.
  - select the `Y` axis and untick `Display tick labels`, `Display tick marks` and `Display axis bar`.

I don't think there is a straightforward way of having the axis end with an arrow, but you can add one from the `Window` -> `Drawing objects` dialog.

About the data: your file should have this format:

```
x0 0 1
x1 0 1
x2 0 1
x3 0 1
x4 0 1
```

where x0, x1, etc are the values at which you want to draw the vertical lines. Import your file via the `Data` -> `Import` -> `ASCII...` dialog, choosing `XYDY` as set type.

Now open the `Plot` -> `Set appearance...` dialog, select the set, set the line type to `None` and change the line color (which affects the bar lines). Go to `Error bars` and set `Bar line` to 0 and the `Riser line` to the width you want. 
If you want to rescale the height of the vertical lines open the `Axis properties` and change the scale of the `Y` axis. Here is an example of how the plot will look like at the end of this procedure:

[image: The final plot]

As I said, it is a very cumbersome procedure but it can be done :-)